# Tensorflow Object Detection API - High RAM/CPU usage - no GPU usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm playing around with the tensorflow Object Detection API, and I'm having some issues with the training of models. In particular, the CPU and Ram usage is very high, while the GPU is basically not used at all (according to Windows task manager):

[image]

I have installed the TF object detection API according to [this guide](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), and I have verified that the GPU is successfully recognised:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

2021-07-20 15:36:37.630320: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:49.683811: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:49.990907: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.605GHz coreCount: 48 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-07-20 15:36:50.017685: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:50.142257: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:50.158525: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:50.173970: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:50.183516: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:50.196516: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:50.213625: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:50.231417: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-07-20 15:36:50.234253: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-07-20 15:36:50.238133: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-07-20 15:36:50.245602: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.605GHz coreCount: 48 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2021-07-20 15:36:50.265550: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-07-20 15:36:54.162700: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-07-20 15:36:54.168506: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0
2021-07-20 15:36:54.169910: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
2021-07-20 15:36:54.176538: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5177 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
tf.Tensor(1222.1837, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

EDIT: I have had this problem only with centernet_hg104_512x512_coco17_tpu-8 (where I am using the pipeline.config file shown below), while other models (ssd_resnet or efficientdet) actually use the gpu.

```
model {
  center_net {
    num_classes: 1
    feature_extractor {
      type: "hourglass_104"
      channel_means: 104.01361846923828
      channel_means: 114.03422546386719
      channel_means: 119.91659545898438
      channel_stds: 73.60276794433594
      channel_stds: 69.89082336425781
      channel_stds: 70.91507720947266
      bgr_ordering: true
    }
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 512
        max_dimension: 512
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    object_detection_task {
      task_loss_weight: 1.0
      offset_loss_weight: 1.0
      scale_loss_weight: 0.10000000149011612
      localization_loss {
        l1_localization_loss {
        }
      }
    }
    object_center_params {
      object_center_loss_weight: 1.0
      classification_loss {
        penalty_reduced_logistic_focal_loss {
          alpha: 2.0
          beta: 4.0
        }
      }
      min_box_overlap_iou: 0.6
      max_box_predictions: 50
    }
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 2
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
      max_aspect_ratio: 1.7000000476837158
      random_coef: 0.25
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_hue {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_contrast {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_saturation {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_adjust_brightness {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_absolute_pad_image {
      max_height_padding: 200
      max_width_padding: 200
      pad_color: 0.0
      pad_color: 0.0
      pad_color: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    adam_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0010000000474974513
          schedule {
            step: 1000
            learning_rate: 9.999999747378752e-05
          }
          schedule {
            step: 5000
            learning_rate: 9.999999747378752e-06
          }
        }
      }
      epsilon: 1.0000000116860974e-07
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-models/centernet_hg104_512x512_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 5000
  max_number_of_boxes: 50
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/test.record"
  }
}
```

The small batch_size of 2 is needed because using any larger number makes the script for training the model get stack for a bit and then quit (this is also quite surprising to me, but I have just started playing around with this stuff so maybe it's actually normal).

I'm using:

Windows 10

CPU: i9-10980HK

ram: 32GB

GPU: GTX3080 8GB dedicated memory

tensorflow = 2.5

CUDA = 11.3.1

cuDNN = 8.2.1.32

Is this low GPU/high CPU usage expected? Am I missing something here?
Thanks for the help, and please let me know if I can provide any other useful info.

Answer (score 2):

In \research\object_detection\legacy\train.py

add the below snippet

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
```

Also faced same issue and it worked for me.