# Tensorflow object detection uses CPU for training, but it detects and uses GPU at the beginning of script

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, resnet

So I have run in to an issue while trying to follow this tutorial:
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

While I am able to run the training script using CPU device, I simply cannot get it to work with my GPU. Specifically, it is the model_main_tf2.py (under the "Training Custom Object Detector" part of the tutorial) that is giving me issues. I have also added the line "tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)" in the script to hopefully get at more comprihensive log.

Oddly enough, it detects the GPU in the beginning of the execution, and (as per my understanding), it uses the GPU for some tasks, but then at some point, it switches to the CPU without any errors... this part of the log is further down the post.

Some system, hardware and software specs:
OS: Ubuntu 20.4
GPU: GTX 1660 Ti Mobile
nvidia-smi output: | NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
tensorflow-gpu version: 2.5.0
tensorflow version: 2.5.0
Python version: 3.9.5

Log where the script switches to CPU use:

```
2021-07-26 17:00:34.027672: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.028022: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.028148: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op NoOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.028357: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.028418: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.028506: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op NoOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.028683: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op VarHandleOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.028741: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op AssignVariableOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.028817: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op NoOp in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/[user]/miniconda3/envs/tensorflowGPU4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:557: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
W0726 17:00:34.090738 140198244909888 deprecation.py:330] From /home/[user]/miniconda3/envs/tensorflowGPU4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:557: StrategyBase.experimental_distribute_datasets_from_function (from tensorflow.python.distribute.distribute_lib) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
rename to distribute_datasets_from_function
2021-07-26 17:00:34.091483: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op HashTableV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.091597: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op LookupTableImportV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.091910: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op HashTableV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.091969: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op LookupTableImportV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.092269: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op HashTableV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.092327: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op LookupTableImportV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.092609: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op HashTableV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
2021-07-26 17:00:34.092666: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:733] Executing op LookupTableImportV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

It would be highly appreciated if anyone could help. At this point, I have pretty much scoured the internet for anyone with the same issue without any luck :/

**EDIT:**
Just an update on my issue. I've tried the exact same setup, with the same OS, graphics driver and CUDA versions and all, on my old computer with a GTX 1060, but I still get the same behavior. I would then guess, that it is just a configuration issue or a misunderstanding somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow Object Detection API - High RAM/CPU usage - no GPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457078/tensorflow-object-detection-api-high-ram-cpu-usage-no-gpu-usage)

Comment: Well, no, but thanks anyway. It turned out that the printout was actually quite normal, but it got stuck later because i had misconfigured some non-mandatory part of the training script. After removing that, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Tutbjun I face the same problem, can u tell the misconfigured that u fixed?

Comment: Of course, but I have to admit, it is a long time ago, so I might remember wrong.
I think it had to do with running the following line from the tutorial:
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config --checkpoint_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn  
I think it had to do with the path in checkpoint_dir, and that it was wrong somehow. If not that, I think it was some other path that was wrong, and then it just stops instead of writing out an error message. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Might be smart to mention, that what actually fixed it was running the command without checkpoint_dir ;) But again, I might remember wrong...

Comment: @Tutbjun thanks for the hints. I would check checkpiont_dir again. I train on mask r-cnn using custom dataset

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your training batch size. Try power of 2. For example : 2,4,8,16.....

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: Sorry about the earlier suggestion. Ignore that.
I had face issues similar to what you had mentioned. Let me explain my scenario first.
The training used to start on the GPU but after short amount of time it switched to CPU on it's own. The CPU usuage after the switch would be about 100%. To solve this issue:
I recreated the tensorflow record file using roboflow. You can

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the earlier suggestion. **Ignore that.**
I had faced issues similar to what you have mentioned. Let me explain my scenario first.
The training used to start on the GPU but after short amount of time it switched to CPU on its own. The CPU usage after the switch would be about 100%.
**To solve this issue:**

I recreated the `tf record file using` roboflow. You can do this by creating a public project on roboflow website. Upload your dataset and they have options to export your dataset in all formats for object detection models.

I think there was some issue with the script that I used to create tf record files earlier. But creating `tf record files` with roboflow solved the issue for me. There you will also be able to do Preprocessing steps and Data augmentation steps and export the `tf record files` after doing that. If you edit your config file and remove the data augmentation steps it will help with your training time also.